# How to fix the issue of Civilization V not launching in "Direct X 10 & 11" mode

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I launch Civlization V from steam and the launcher appears, it gives me the option of Direct X 9, Direct X 10 & 11 or Windows 8 Touch Enabled Mode. I wish to run it in DX11 so I select that, the window then disappears then nothing happens. How can I launch it in DX11 mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just spent about 30 minutes seeking this solution but I finally figured it out. I know how frustrating it can be to find straightforward answers to problems and I don't want the time I spent figuring this out to be wasted. If I can help one person it is worth it. Anyways here is how I fixed it.

All you have to do is install this official version of DirectX from Microsoft. I don't know why but this solved my problem immediately.

Here is the link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35

Have fun and enjoy